# Casting with TULargeInteger in delphi 10.2 Tokyo differ from previous version

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Casting with TULargeInteger with new compiler 10.2 missing attribut LowPart and HighPart.

```
uses Winapi.Windows;

    function RetLargeInt: Int64;
    var
      ALow: DWORD;

    begin
      {Do Something
        With ALow
      }
      TULargeInteger(Result).LowPart := ALow; {Missing 'LowPart'}
    end;

    procedure AProc;
    var
     ALocalInt: Int64;
    begin
      ALocalInt := RetLargeInt;
      {Do Something}
    end;
```

Comment: Or use Int64Rec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 10.2 Tokyo, the declaration of `TULargeInteger` has changed from:

```
TULargeInteger = ULARGE_INTEGER;
```

to :

```
TULargeInteger = UInt64;
```

This means that you can no longer access the `ULARGE_INTEGER` record fields that exposes `LowPart`.

> ```
> ULARGE_INTEGER = record
>     case Integer of
>     0: (
>       LowPart: DWORD;
>       HighPart: DWORD);
>     1: (
>       QuadPart: ULONGLONG);
>   end;
> ```

---

You can change the code to use `ULARGE_INTEGER` instead:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER(Result).LowPart := ALow;
```